# Horizontal scroll is added incorrectly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Do you know what is causing the horizontal scroll om my webpage?

[Link to the webpage](http://#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a text-indent of 20000px on #logo

```
@media screen
    #logo {
    background-image: url('images/logo.png');
    width: 150px;
    height: 28px;
    text-indent: 20000px;   <--- here's the culprit!!!
}
```

user Globin (http://stackoverflow.com/users/848053/globin) notes that there  there is also a mistake with the Facebook button:

`<dic>` should be `<div>`

Comment: Great, I didn't notice that. Instead of a text-intendent I put the text into a <span> and added a -3000px left margin.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding in a container div. You want to wrap your entire page (from the opening body to the closing body tag in a div. Perhaps someone else can comment on why this is needed? Because i am not sure of this.

```
<body class="home blog">
  <div id="wrapper">
    REST OF PAGE
  </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper
  {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```